# Pyrus install error

Tags: xml, zend-framework, pyrus

I am trying to install zend framework 2 using pyrus but i get a strange error on pyrus install : `Pyrus\Config\Exception: Unable to parse invalid PEAR configuration at "."
 Pyrus\Config\Exception: Document is empty
  Pyrus\Config\Exception: Start tag expected, '<' not found`

My config is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pearconfig version="1.0">
     <default_channel>pear2.php.net</default_channel>
     <auto_discover>0</auto_discover>
     <http_proxy></http_proxy>
     <cache_dir>~/.pear/cache</cache_dir>
     <temp_dir>~/.pear/temp</temp_dir>
     <verbose>1</verbose>
     <preferred_state>stable</preferred_state>
     <umask>0022</umask>
     <cache_ttl>3600</cache_ttl>
     <my_pear_path>.</my_pear_path>
     <plugins_dir>/home/sebastian/.pear</plugins_dir>
</pearconfig>
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a `pearconfig.xml` in your current directory. Is that the one you posted? If not, simply remove it.

Also try to find out which config it really tries to load, e.g. with strace:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=open pyrus get
```

One of the files is the config file it loads, and it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

You don't state your platform but the above error happens with a fresh install on OS X, and maybe other platforms, if you ask for the packages to be installed at your home directory. Ask instead for them to be installed in a subdirectory.

So

```
/Users/youraccount/pear
```

rather than

```
/Users/youraccount
```

in response to the pyrus install question.

To remove the corrupted configuration:

```
rm -r ~/.pear*
```